# How to update xml element value?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to update the value of `<Bytes>` tag from xml file and then saving it into new `output.xml` file. I am doing it write but I don't know why it's not working.The xml file is huge more then 20000 lines having data in between the `<OLDDATA>` and `<NEWDATA>` tag.  i only wats to update data in between `<NEWDATA>` tag. Also note that value of all tags are of string datatype. Down below is my xml data and code.

```
#this is my xml data
...
<NEWData>
<SlNo>106</SlNo>
<Parameter>Cycle Time</Parameter>
<Bytes>3</Bytes>
<MinValue>2</MinValue>
</NEWData>

<OLDData>
<SlNo>107</SlNo>
<Parameter>Cycle Time</Parameter>
<Bytes>3</Bytes>
<MinValue>2</MinValue>
</OLDData>

<NEWData>
<SlNo>108</SlNo>
<Parameter>Cycle Time</Parameter>
<Bytes>7</Bytes>
<MinValue>1</MinValue>
</NEWData>
...
#this is my code

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(complet_path)
root = tree.getroot()
ln = len(root)

for i in range(ln):
    newDataTag = root[i].tag
    if newDataTag=='NEWDATA':
        parameter=root[i][1].text
        bytes = root[i][4].text
        minValue = root[i][11].text

        if bytes=="3":
           bytes ="5"
           minValue ="1"
           bytes.set('updated', 'yes')
        if bytes=="7":
           bytes ="4"
           minValue ="0"
           bytes.set('updated', 'yes')
tree.write('output.xml')
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error? Unexpected output? Something else?

Comment: it's not updating the values in the `output.xml` file the original xml file and output file is same nothing is updated also it's not shoing any error. @larsks7

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r>
<NEWData>
<SlNo>106</SlNo>
<Parameter>Cycle Time</Parameter>
<Bytes>3</Bytes>
<MinValue>2</MinValue>
</NEWData>

<NEWData>
<SlNo>107</SlNo>
<Parameter></Parameter>
<Bytes>7</Bytes>
<MinValue>1</MinValue>
</NEWData>

<NEWData>
<SlNo>108</SlNo>
<Parameter></Parameter>
<Bytes>111</Bytes>
<MinValue>1</MinValue>
</NEWData>
</r>'''

LOOK_UP = {'3':('5','1'),'7': ('4','0')}

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for nd in root.findall('.//NEWData'):
  bytes = nd.find('Bytes')
  min_value = nd.find('MinValue')
  _bytes,_min_value = LOOK_UP.get(bytes.text,('0','0'))
  bytes.text = _bytes
  min_value.text = _min_value
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<r>
<NEWData>
<SlNo>106</SlNo>
<Parameter>Cycle Time</Parameter>
<Bytes>5</Bytes>
<MinValue>1</MinValue>
</NEWData>

<NEWData>
<SlNo>107</SlNo>
<Parameter />
<Bytes>4</Bytes>
<MinValue>0</MinValue>
</NEWData>

<NEWData>
<SlNo>108</SlNo>
<Parameter />
<Bytes>0</Bytes>
<MinValue>0</MinValue>
</NEWData>
</r>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Also I have made some changes in the question it will be helpful if you read it one more time. And there is no logic in the updating values they are just strings getting it from some where else. @balderman

Comment: @zircon See my updated answer

Comment: how to save the output data into new xml file?will this `root.write('output.xml')` work? @balderman

Comment: Does the new logic work for you? Did you try and save the file?